# passing values to a boolean array

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

I'm working on a simple 2d game engine, and am trying to set up a system where the player model can move behind certain objects. Every time an non-player object is blitted to the screen, its X and Y are recorded in an array so they can be used later. As such, I have set up a system where if the player X and player Y are relative to an environmental object's X and Y in a certain way, the environmental object is not immediately blitted (Normally, it would be immediately blitted before the player character so that the player character is above the object). Instead of being blitted, I have a true value be handed to a boolean array. I have an int variable that gets 1 larger every time an object is blitted so that the different X, Y and boolean values are associated with a certain position in the array. Essentially, the system looks like this:

```
HDcounter += 1;

forbiddenX[HDcounter] = modelX[modelNumber] + modelXChange;
forbiddenY[HDcounter] = modelY[modelNumber] + modelYChange;
forbiddenSpriteWidth[HDcounter] = 100;
forbiddenSpriteHeight[HDcounter] = 200;
forbiddenSpriteDepth[HDcounter] = 25;

if((forbiddenX[HDcounter] <= playerXE + forbiddenSpriteWidth[HDcounter]) && (forbiddenX[HDcounter] + forbiddenSpriteWidth[HDcounter] >= playerXE) && (forbiddenY[HDcounter] <= playerYE + forbiddenSpriteWidth[HDcounter]) && (forbiddenY[HDcounter] + forbiddenSpriteHeight[HDcounter] >= playerYE + 77))
{
     pineTreeBlitAP = true;
     blitModelAP[HDcounter] = true;
}
else
{
     modelIMAGE = IBFobjectENVIRO.loadIMG("pineTree.png");
     IBFobjectENVIRO.blitIMG(modelX[modelNumber] + modelXChange, modelY[modelNumber] +   modelYChange, windowMODELS, modelIMAGE, 0, 0, 200, 200);
}
```

The problem is that when I try to use the boolean array to blit the model after the player, it does not seem to work. I can get something to happen when the player X and Y hits the threshold, but I cannot seem to get the true value recorded inside the boolean array and then used by my function. 
This is the function where it is used:

```
void enviroment::blitEnviroModelsAP(SDL_Surface* BAPwindow, int modelAmount)
{
    SDL_Surface* modelAPimage;

    for(int model = 0; model < modelAmount; model++)
    {
        if((pineTreeBlitAP == true) && (blitModelAP[model] == true))
        {
            modelAPimage = IBFobjectENVIRO.loadIMG("pineTree.png");
            IBFobjectENVIRO.blitIMG(forbiddenX[model], forbiddenY[model], BAPwindow, modelAPimage, 0, 0, 200, 200);
        }
    }
}
```

I get that this is probably a totally noob question, I just want some kind of help with this as I have been stuck for nearly a week.

Edit: Here are how my arrays are declared.

```
int forbiddenX[2000] = {0}; 
int forbiddenY[2000] = {0}; 
int forbiddenSpriteHeight[2000] = {0}; 
int forbiddenSpriteWidth[2000] = {0}; 
int forbiddenSpriteDepth[2000] = {0};
int blitModelAP[2000] = {false};
```

Comment: Can you please describe more precisely want is your and problem (actual output) and expected output ?

Comment: Essentially when my player X and Y get within a certain distance, the function clearly recognizes that it is within that distance (because the object stops blitting) however something is going wrong because what should be happening is the object doesn't stop blitting, it would only blit after the player has been blitted.

Comment: Please add some more context, e.g., on pastebin.com or ideone.com. What type is blitModelAP?

Comment: Yes thanks for changes, but however some more information is required what are the input data. How is the functional called. It is quite hard to understand details without the context. Can you provide a main function that calls the respective misbehavior.